# An error was encountered when contacting the add-on partner to create cleardb:ignite

Tags: mysql, heroku, cleardb

I deployed my application in Heroku approximately one month ago and I deployed with ClearDB and I also use MySQL Workbench. There is no problem in ClearDB before but since last week, I have reached max_question and max_user limit exceeds and today, I got unable root user error. Then, I tried to solve this problem but I couldn't get it and I decided reinstall clearDB and I deleted clearDB add ons and MySQL Workbench connection. But I didn't add add ons of clearDB, system gave error like this.

Item could not be created:
An error was encountered when contacting the add-on partner to create cleardb:ignite. Please try again later.

I also tried to open another project and add it because maybe there is a problem in the project I am in, but it did not add it either.

Is there a problem in clearDB now?
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be a problem with ClearDB today. Check this other topic
[Heroku is not connecting to database NodeJS and Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72274348/heroku-is-not-connecting-to-database-nodejs-and-mysql/72276124#72276124) . Although your issue is a bit different, it might be related

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I read the your posted problem, it seems to be same. I use Spring Boot but I received same problem. I will wait.